# Delphi COM Passing ByteArray as OleVariant

Tags: c++, vb.net, delphi, delphi-xe

I'm interfacing fingerprint reader via COM and i need help converting VB.NET and C++ Code to Delphi.

The API takes olevariant as parameter:

```
Function FingerPrint.GetData(var ImageData : OleVariant) : WordBool;
```

VB.NET example provided:

```
Dim imgData() as Byte
ReDim imgData(fingerPrint.ImageSize) as Byte

If fingerPrint.GetData(imgData) = True Then  
   'Success
End If
```

C++ example provided:

```
BYTE* dataBuff = new BYTE[fingerPrint.ImageSize];
VARIANT imgData;

imgData.vt = VT_BYREF|VT_UI1;
imgData.pbVal = dataBuff;

if(fingerPrint.getData(imgData) == TRUE) {
  //Success
}
```

Here's my Delphi Code:

```
procedure GetImgData();
var varBuffer : OleVariant;
    imgBuff : PByteArray;
begin
     GetMem(imgBuff, fingerPrint.ImageSize);

     try
        tagVariant(varBuffer).vt    := VT_UI1 or VT_BYREF; // 0x4011
        tagVariant(varBuffer).pbVal := Pointer(imgBuff);

        if fingerPrint.getData(varBuffer) then
        begin
             // success
        end;
     finally
        FreeMem(imgBuff);
     end;
end;
```

another approach:

```
procedure GetImgData();
var varBuffer : OleVariant;
    tagV : TVariantArg;
    imgBuff : PByteArray;
begin
     GetMem(imgBuff, fingerPrint.ImageSize);

     try
        tagV.vt    := VT_UI1 or VT_BYREF; // 0x4011
        tagV.pbVal := Pointer(imgBuff);

        varBuffer  := OleVariant(tagV);

        if fingerPrint.getData(varBuffer) then
        begin
             // success
        end;
     finally
        FreeMem(imgBuff);
     end;
end;
```

getData is not returning true using the parameter i'm sending. Sent my executable to support and told me that API is getting 0x400C (VT_VARIANT or VT_BYREF) instead of 0x4011.

Anything wrong with my Code?

Please Help!

UPDATE:

here's from dispinterface

```
function GetData(var ImageData: OleVariant): WordBool; dispid 23;
```

from Component Wrapper

```
..
function GetData(var ImageData : OleVariant): WordBool;
..
function TFingerPrint.GetData(var ImageData : OleVariant): WordBool;
begin
  Result := DefaultInterface.GetData(ImageData);
end;
```

C++ declaration

```
BOOL getData(const VARIANT FAR& imgData)
```

UPDATE 20140313

Our supplier sent new OCX to handle data received from Delphi.

Comment: Please can you check the details. The C# code is actually C++ I believe. If so, the function parameters don't match. The C++ code takes a VARIANT struct by value. Unless the function arg takes a reference.  Your Delphi code passes Variant by var. So, more details please. Include the function declarations for getData in at least two languages.

Comment: When I try to recreate what you describe, the var type comes across just fine as `0x4011`. I think there's an error in your signature at the interop boundary. So I do think we need to see more.

Comment: Please can you add more details, and correct the errors in an edit. I think once you've done that we can wrap it up. FWIW, I think it's a mistake to case `OleVariant` to `tagVariant`. You may as well use a variable that really is `tagVariant` and adapt the function signature to match.

Comment: Would really appreciate if you can tell me more about that error in signature at the interop boundary

Comment: I'd love to. You'll need to show the signatures though! You give the Delphi signature only. Please show the C++ declaration of `getData`. Once you do that it should be straight forward.

Comment: COM wrapper is delphi generated and i have no option but to convert tagVariant to OleVariant or cast olevariant as tagVariant to assign vt and pbVal

Comment: You certainly do have that option. Anyway, if you refuse to show more details, I cannot help you. Let me know if you decide to reveal more information.

Comment: you mean this -> BOOL getData(const VARIANT FAR& imgData)?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean! That needs to go in the question mind you. What is the calling convention in the C++ code?

Comment: this is from delphi generated COM Wrapper -> function GetData(var ImageData : OleVariant): WordBool; dispid 23;

Comment: That last comment looks wrong. Surely there is a `safecall` specified. Please will you stop leaking the details out in comments. Take some time and put them in the question. Lots of detail is good here. This is binary interop. The nitty gritty is everything.

Comment: there's no safecall, actually i was also expecting that. 

here's from dispinterface
function GetData(var ImageData: OleVariant): WordBool; dispid 23;

from Component Wrapper
..
function GetData(var imgData: OleVariant): WordBool;
..
function TFingerPrint.GetData(var ImageData : OleVariant): WordBool;
begin
  Result := DefaultInterface.GetData(ImageData);
end;

Comment: ahh ok sorry.. i will edit the question

Comment: Well, according to the code in your latest edits, the C++ function uses cdecl. Which I guess is not the case. Surely there's a calling convention. Anyway, I guess dispinterface or dispid imply safecall. It's pretty weird. My test environment shows your code working fine.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan. I'll play around more and update you as soon as a fix this

Comment: It's pretty weird. Is it possible that the code to make a call to the  dispinterface is mangling your variant? Try looking under the debugger.

Comment: It's pretty weird to have a varByRef to one byte, and write to any more bytes that happen to be there. Gives the smell of a vulnerability attack vector. And makes me think Delphi's variant handling could misbehave. And still VB still passes in a 'plain' array of bytes?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's 0x4011 and not 0x2011? Since `varArray = $2000` and `VarArrayCreate([0,size-1],varByte)` would create an OleVariant with an array of varByte's like the VB code. If that works, use `VarArrayLock` and `VarArrayUnlock` to access the data.

Comment: That's a safearray. He wants VT_BYREF.

Comment: @jdc: have you tried? It is what should be going on behind the scenes of the VB version

Comment: @StijnSanders Hmm. The C++ example code does look bogus. Perhaps that's the problem.

Comment: @StijnSanders. Yup. i tried it because that's the next solution that came into my mind after reading VB Sample. `VarArrayCreate` flags `varArray` which fills `VARRAY`. The API really needs `VT_UI1 | VT_BYREF`

Comment: `VarArrayCreate` is also the most compatible code based on VB sample, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: I aready tried using `VarArrayLock` and `VarArrayUnlock`, used `VarArrayRef` to flag `varByRef` but no one worked.

Comment: @jdc You should ask the developer of the OCX why they think it is fine to pass multiple bytes through `VT_UI1 | VT_BYREF`. I assumed that was reasonable when I first read the question, but it does indeed seem to be bogus. I'm not sure I trust anything that this developer says.